# call another module on a onCLickListener button click

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to call another module within my original module. Below I have my two modules: app and app1:

[image]

below is my MainActivity for the module app:

```
package com.example.mainscreen

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var button: Button


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)


       val b = findViewById<View>(R.id.button2) as Button
        b.setOnClickListener { startActivity(Intent(this@MainActivity, Pop::class.java)) }




        button = findViewById<View>(R.id.button) as Button
        button.setOnClickListener {
            finish()
            System.exit(0)
        }}}
```

How would I use the OnClickListener for the button from my module app to call the MainActivity file from app2? I am not entirely sure how to approach this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use another way to create your `Intent`. I should use `setComponent` method.

```
val intent = Intent()
// ComponentName("The package name of the activity that you wish to launch","Its fully qualified class name"))
intent.setComponent(ComponentName("com.example.mainscreen", "com.example.mainscreen.MainActivity"))
startActivity(intent)
```

Comment: thanks but the activity I want to launch is in app1 and when I type it in `intent.setComponent` it does not come up. Am I missing  a step?

Comment: @AdamNewman `app1` is a module of `app`. `app1` is inside `app`. You can access `app1`'s classes from `app`, but can't `app`'s classes from `app1`. So you can't start  `MainActivity` that inside `app` module from `app1` using `Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)`. To solve this issue you need use my approach where you enter package name and class name manually. Hint should not come out.